# Snowflake's Go driver doesn't support Read-Only Transactions. Why?

Tags: transactions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, readonly

I'm trying to use Snowflake's Go driver to start a Read-Only transaction, but received a `263000 (0A000): no readonly mode is supported`. This is returned by: https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/blob/e08419dfe80500613bda2f4e9be6ad17f7107881/connection.go#L162-L167.

Just wondering if this a limitation of the Go driver, or the Snowflake system itself?

In Go's `database/sql` package, you can start a Read-Only transaction by running the following code:

```
db.BeginTxx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{ReadOnly: true})
```

This is useful when you want to guard against accidental writes during your transaction. However, not sure if Snowflake allows this.

Comment: Snowflake support only 1 isolation level i.e. read-committed, unlike many other RDBMSs that support usually 3 (or 4). https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#isolation-level.   Transactions in snowflake - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/begin.html#begin

Comment: If you want to avoid “writes” use a role that cannot write would be more aligned than a transaction that blocks it.